# How can I fix a button that is clicked but does not perform any actions?

Tags: selenium

So I'm currently working on a new project and I need to write some automated tests.

I came across a problem and I don't know how to fix it. If the button of my web page is clicked running selenium it doesn't perform any actions, but if I open the web page manualy and click on the button, everything works fine.

NOTE: I'm completely sure that the xpath is correct and the button is being clicked...

This is what happens running with selenium:

[image]

And this is what happens openning the web page manually and clicking on the button:
[image]

Comment: There's a chance that the button is receiving a `click` event but doesn't do anything with that event. As a workaround, can you try clicking with `Actions`? Selenium actually doesn't use mouse-like clicks with the normal `click()` method, and your site may need to have a `mouseDown`-like event. Ask your developers to fix this to accept `click` events ***if this is the case***, it makes it much easier and less fragile.

Comment: I actually tried to click the button using the mouse when the page was being used by selenium and nothing happened too....

Comment: Check the url that your are accessing with selenium. is it same? the url has any attribute?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials